# Eliminate repeats and list second column in single cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large set of data (40,000+ rows) and it is all multiple id numbers. They are listed in column 1. Then in column 10, i have a SsoftGroup name for multiple job posts they qualify. I would like to take what I have and pull to a separate tab the data that I need...

What I have...

> ```
> Column 1   Column 10
> EmplNum    SsoftGroup
> 1          Assembly
> 1          Assembly
> 1          Cleaning
> 2          Bakery
> 2          Assembly
> 2          Assembly
> 2          Bakery
> 3          Cleaning
> 3          Cleaning
> 3          Bakery
> 3          Assembly
> 3          Assembly
> 4          Bakery
> 4          Bakery
> ```

What I need in another tab

> ```
> Column 1       Column 2
> 1              Staff Assembly:Staff Cleaning
> 2              Staff Assembly:Staff Bakery
> 3              Staff Assembly:Staff Bakery:Staff Cleaning
> 4              Staff Bakery
> ```

I am not sure how to do this since I am not very familiar with VBA of Macros. I know a concatenate could be used for Column 2 of what I need; I am just not sure how to do it since there is a variable array size.

Comment: For a VBA solution a collection or dictionary would be the way to go. For standard excel functionality, this is an ideal use-case for pivot tables. I posted as answer to include screenshot

Comment: For VBA function see below

Comment: Argument 2 is the range of your data (in my answer screenshot: F5:G18). Assume that the range you select for arg 2 is J5:M18, say. That is a total of 4 Cols. If you want to refer to this range via a name, then you have to name this range, `J5:M18`, as `SsoftGroup`, in Excel, or whatever name you want. The function assumes that the Job col is always the last column of your data range. So it will ignore the data in cols in K and L and just use Col J to find the data in Col M. Only the 1st and Last rows matter. See new screenshot I attached to my answer showing the function working.

Comment: consider marking an answer if any of these solutions have helped you, so that other users may find the answer if they search for this question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot tables. From this, you can get virtually any information you want using simple excel `count` and `if` and `sum` functions. That is if the pivot does not already provide you with the information you want.

[image: pivot]

If you want to implement a VBA function to use in a worksheet, you can use this:

```
Function JobCat(ByVal BaseValue, ByRef rng As Range, ByVal delim As String) As String
Dim a, i, k As Long
Dim last_col As Integer


Set jobs = New Collection
last_col = rng.Columns.Count

a = rng.Value
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
        If Val(a(i, 1)) = Val(BaseValue) Then
            jobs.Add "Staff " & a(i, last_col), "Staff " & a(i, last_col)
        End If
    Next


    For k = 1 To jobs.Count
        JobCat = JobCat & IIf(JobCat = "", "", delim) & jobs.Item(k)
    Next
End Function
```

With argument 1 is the EmplNum, argument 2 is the whole range (both columns) and argument 3 is the text delimiter (as in ":" or "," etc). As in this screenshot

[image]

Updated to show it working with a named range:

[image: named_range]

Comment: will it work if i name an argument ssoftlink and use that as argument 2

Comment: i got it to work, but when i drag down the function output column, it isnt consistent, for example, not all the function outputs are the same for a givin empl number

Comment: yes it works. But you have to first create a named range, and the first Col of this named range must be EmpNum data and the last Col must be SoftGroup data. Anything in between is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Dictionary` object which stores data in Key/Value pairs. The `Value` part can be any data type, so we will just use a string & concatenate the various items from column B, for unique ID value in column A.

**About the dictionary...**

A dictionary *creates* the key/value two ways, either explicitly through the `.Add` method,

```
dict.Add "key", "value"
```

or implicitly by referencing a key that doesn't yet exist:

```
dict("key") = "value"
```

The latter will overwrite an existing value *if* the key already exists. so we can use the `.Exists` method that returns boolean to see if the item already exists.

```
If dict.Exists("key") then 
    dict("key") = dict("key") & " some other text!"
Else
    dict.Add "key", "value"
End If
```

In your case we just use the `Instr` function to check and see if that value from Column B has already been appended to the `Value` for each ID from column A.

Untested, but I think this should do it:

```
Sub foo()
Dim dict as Object
Dim rng as Range
Dim r as Range
Dim val as String
Dim id as String
Dim key as Variant
Dim i as Long

Set rng = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)) 'Modify as needed
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

'iterate the range.rows:
For each r in rng.Rows
    '
    id = r.Value

    'get the value from the same row, cell in column 10 and prefix with "Staff "
    val = "Staff " & r.Offset(0,9).Value

    'Add this item if it doesn't already exist:
    If Not dict.Exists(id) Then 
        dict.Add id, val
    Else
        'avoid printing duplicate "values" in the dictionary using some string functions:
        If Instr(1, dict(id), val) = 0 Then
            dict(id) = dict(id) & ":" & val
        End If
    End If

Next

'Print the data to another sheet in columns A, B:
With Worksheets("Sheet2")          '<~~ MODIFY AS NEEDED TO USE YOUR SHEET NAME
    For each key in dict.Keys()
        .Range("A1").Offset(i).Value = key
        .Range("B1").Offset(i).Value = dict(key)
        i = i + 1
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar or comfortable with VBA and the above solution is intimidating, you can also accomplish your goal using just a couple of Excel functions and a lot of extra columns.

Basically, you would create a table that counts each instance of an unique employee ID matching to each unique job group. You just have to put the de-duplicated list of employee ids in the leftmost column of the table, and a de-duplicated list of job groups in the topmost row (use the transpose command).

Here's a sample of what it should look like using your example data:

```
Column 1    Assembly    Cleaning    Bakery      ...     Column 2
1                                                 
2   
3   
4   
...
```

Then you can use COUNTIFS(...) to put a logical value in each cell of the table that can be used in an IF(...) statement to either return a blank cell or a string... and then you just concatenate every cell in that row in your final column.

I used this formula in the table cells and it worked fine (obviously you'll have to change the sheet name and adjust cell references):

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A, $B4, Sheet1!$B:$B, D$2) > 0, "Staff " & D$2 & ":", "")
```

Do you know how many *unique* job groups are in column 10 in your whole data set? Concatenating a lot of cells in a row can be quite tedious, so if it's over 50, you probably should just go the VBA route.

Comment: There is a 153 unique values in column 10 and 553 unique values in column 1 but it this gets updated regularly